# I am trying to schedule an ionic cordova background geolocation plugin.Is it possible?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, geolocation, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am using this below plugin for getting background geolocation from android application,
https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation

Is there any possible way to somehow stop the plugin after eight hours or schedule it for specific period of time.
Below is my ionic info,

cli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-proxy : 1.4.13
@ionic/cli-utils        : 1.13.1
ionic (Ionic CLI)       : 3.13.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
Node              : v6.10.2
npm               : 5.5.1
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of doing this is to use the background-mode plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-background-mode

You can use this plugin and setInterval() together to run functions in the background of the app.